# Ubuntu installer won't let me install to my USB?

Tags: partitioning, usb

I am new to these forums and I have limited experience with linux so bear with me.
I am using my 16 gigabyte usb stick to install xubuntu onto itself. I had entered the installer and chose to manually partition the drive, creating a partition for root and another for swap. When I pressed okay, I got a dialog box saying "Failed to create partition for swap partition (1024 megabytes)" and I got sent back to the previous steps in the installation process. I even tried creating a partition table that did't even include a swap partition and that time I got a message saying "Failed to create partition for root partition (15 gigabytes, formatted to ext4)". Why is it that every time I create a partition, I get a message that says that it has failed to be created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easier way to do this is either use a Linux Image that allows for persistence, or you need to do this with the use of a CD/DVD/USB and a Separate USB stick.  This way the Kubuntu install doesn't get upset when you are running gparted to edit the partition structure.  Universal USB Installer(for Windows) allows for persistence with certain images.  (This essentially allows you to install Linux to the usb and boot it keeping your changes every boot.  It is NOT as good as having it truly installed to a USB however.  You do know that all USB sticks have a maximum number of read and writes before they fail, so I would suggest an external HDD for maximum system life)

Comment: I had a separate USB stick lying around so I decided to go with your suggestion and it successfully partitioned and installed! Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Blender I am so glad!...Hope you have success in your future ventures.